# How do I get my Samsung Galaxy S 2 to connect by USB "normally"?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-2, usb-connection-mode

***Note:** This question has been edited significantly based on new information, however, I think it still meets the original intent.*

I have a Samsung Galaxy S 2. When I plug it into my computer by USB, this application called "Samsung Kies" comes up. It is, as far as I can tell, a proprietary Samsung system for connecting by USB to the computer which requires software on the computer side.

Even if my computer could run their software, I wouldn't want it to. I don't want their proprietary app, I just want to mount the Galaxy as an external USB HD, like Android does with its standard interface.

I can get at the standard interface by doing the following:

> Settings -> Wireless and network -> USB Utlities

In that interface, under the heading "USB mass storage", there is a button that says "Connect storage to PC". If I click this button, a notification comes up saying I can now plug in the USB. If I plug in the USB cable at this point, *then* the usual Android interface comes up (green android with USB arm picture) and then I can press the connect button.

So I can do it, but I have to press the screen ***5 times*** just to connect the USB!

With my previous phone, the HTC Magic, when I plugged in the USB, it automatically showed me the standard USB connect screen, and so with one touch I could connect.

I can't find any way of disabling or removing this unwanted Samsung Kies software, or making the standard Android USB connect the default.

Is this possible, and if so, how?

Comment: While the devices show up, they shouldn't be mounted.  To mount internal storage (or the SD card) you need to click the notification on your phone.  This is how it works with my original SGS on Windows, anyways.

Comment: try keeping usb debugging on by default.

Comment: @Aadi Droid: That answer seems to work. Why don't you post it as an answer and not a comment? I want to test it for a day or so to be sure it works consistently. If it does continue to work, you should be the one to collect the bounty on the answer.

Comment: done buddy :) glad it worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Keep usb debugging on and it should work fine.