# How to recover application data after deleting it from the settings menu?

Tags: internal-storage, data-recovery, chrome-for-android, bookmarks

I wanted to cancel a download, which I did until now by long-tapping on it, then "App Info" button and killing the download manager and deleting its data.

However, this time, the "App Info" button opened up the app settings for Chrome and not for the download manager, which I only noticed after I deleted all the data!

Is there a way to undo that or at least somehow extract my bookmarks from the (Huawei Y3300 mobile phone's) internal storage device?

Note: By "app settings" I mean the page where you can "Stop Now" "Uninstall" "Disable" "Delete All Data" "Clear Cache" "Reset Default Associations" for given app.

Note: I suspect the cause for this mistake is that for "normal" downloads the download manager opens up if tapping on "App Info" but this was a "Save Video" download, for which apparently Chrome is still responsible.

Comment: possible duplicate: http://android.stackexchange.com/q/56797/1465

Comment: Did you have sync enabled for Chrome?

Comment: @Firelord no I did not